# passing variable defined as files to os.system()

Tags: variables, python-2.7, os.system

I am trying to write a short program that would pass variables for a os.system(). Where the variables are defined as following:

```
code = 'code.py'
input_file = 'input.xxxx'
output_file = 'output.xxxx'


import os
os.system("python code input_file output_file")
```

The code works when i specify it as

```
import os
os.system("python code.py input.xxxx output.xxxx")
```

But not with variables. 
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt at it is passing a string made up of variable *names*, not their *values*. Try this:

```
os.system("python {} {} {}".format(code, input_file, output_file)) # Python 3.x
```

or

```
os.system("python {0} {1} {2}".format(code, input_file, output_file)) # Python 2.x
```

That will insert the variable values into the string for you.

Comment: Good! I'm glad it helped. You should [mark one of the available answers as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) when you have one that meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

python doesnt recognize the variable names inside quotations. youll have to concatenate the string and the variables like so:

```
os.system("python " + code + " " + input_file + " " + output_file);
```

now i forget if python + automatically adds a space or not so you might not need those " " or the space after python

Comment: It works just the way you suggested (with all the spaces and ""). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: no problem im glad it worked for you and now im sure about whether python need the spaces or not haha